# Use of "RecordCondition.ExcludeIfMatchRegex"

Tags: filehelpers

Library version: v2.0.0.0

I would like to use `ExcludeIfMatchRegex` to exclude certain lines in the input file.

I have tested next code but the system is displaying the usual message error *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*.
If I remove the line containing "ConditionalRecord", the system reads the file and returns the usual validation messages.

```cs
using FileHelpers;
using System;

[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[ConitionalRecord(RecordCondition.ExcludeIfMatchRegex, "[0-9 A-Za-z.,]{1}S[0-9 A-Za-z.,]{10}")] 
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
public sealed class PurchaseOrder : INotifyRead
{
    [FieldFixedLength(1)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string C;
        
    [FieldFixedLength(1)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string A;
        
    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string item;

    public void AfterRead(EngineBase engine, string line)
    {
          // not exist the property "SkipThisRecord"??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a small bug in the 2.0.0.0 library.

When the FileHelpers engine reads a file but ALL lines are excluded AND the class is decorated with INotifyRead it throws the *Object Reference* error.

However you can work around it by using the AfterReadRecord event instead.

```
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.ExcludeIfMatchRegex, "[0-9 A-Za-z.,]{1}S[0-9 A-Za-z.,]{10}")]
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
public sealed class PurchaseOrder
{
    [FieldFixedLength(1)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string C;

    [FieldFixedLength(1)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string A;

    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string item;
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(PurchaseOrder));
        // use the AfterReadRecord event instead of the INotifyRead interface
        engine.AfterReadRecord += Engine_AfterReadRecord;

        // The record will be skipped because of the Regex
        var records = engine.ReadString("0S0123456789");
        Debug.Assert(records.Length == 0);

        Console.Write("All OK. No records were imported.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    // Define the event here instead of in your FileHelpers class
    private static void Engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, AfterReadRecordEventArgs e)
    {
        // not exist the property "SkipThisRecord"??
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @shampoo. My drawback is the source code because I cannot modify our program and only I can use the INotifyRead interface.